# Pandas read_csv with date in 2 columns

Tags: pandas

I have a csv file with the following format:

```
10/09/2009,08:16,99.835,99.835,99.835,99.835,2
```

How do I call `pandas.read_csv` on such a file so that it parses the first 2 columns as a datetime index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `parse_dates` kwarg in the read_csv function. See [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_goes_here, sep=',', parse_dates={'dt': [0, 1]}).set_index('dt')
```

You can also use the `date_parser` kwarg if you have dates in nonstandard formats (the ones in this example are standard).